# python Image pixel editing

Tags: python, image

I'm working on a program where I open an image file(jpg), edit some of the pixels, and save the image with a new file name. It seems, however, that even when I am not editing any pixels, they are still being altered. This is a quick sample I wrote up. All I am doing is opening an image and saving it with a different name.

```
import Image

img1 = Image.open('image.jpg')
print img1.getpixel((0,0))
img1.save('testimage.jpg')

img2 = Image.open('testimage.jpg')
print img2.getpixel((0,0))
```

The output of the first print statement is (253,254,248) and the output of the second is (253,251,255). Why are the Green and Blue values changing if I am doing absolutely nothing to the image?

Comment: image.jpg and testimage.jpg are exactly the same? I don't see you saving any image? Is there any difference between the pixels if you look in an image editing program? Given that it's a jpeg, the simple act of opening and saving might alter the image ever so slightly.

Comment: I ran this code on a simple jpeg image, and received the same color for each image. Can you give us a link to the image you're using?

Comment: I was just using that as an example to show that it was altering the pixels just by opening it and then saving it. I switched to using a png instead thanks to nneonneo's answewr. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPEGs are lossy: saving a JPEG may result in quality loss and thus changed pixels. If you want to edit without (further) losing quality, save as `.png` or some other lossless format instead.

Comment: wow, I knew it would be something little like that. I haven't worked with images much so I had no idea. Thanks Alot!